# visual studio: unable to delete folder this function is not supported on this system

Tags: visual-studio-2010

Appparantly I'm the only one on the Internet experiencing this problem because I can find ZERO other reports of anyone else encountering it. Unfortunately I've been dealing with it for months and I don't know what else to do.

sometimes when I attempt to delete a folder from visual studio 2010, I get the error

> unable to delete folder 'XXXX' this function is not supported on this
>   system

I can't delete it from the file system either unless I reboot the machine. Apparently there is a lock on it somewhere, but I can't find it. I tried to use Unlocker, but that doesn't work on Windows 7 x64 so I'm stuck.

This happens most often with the App_Theme folder, though it happens with other folders as well.

I would suspect it has something to do with source control (we are using sourcegear fortress), however I've encountered this error at home on my personal projects, and I don't use source control on that...

so does anyone have any ideas? has **anyone** out there experienced this issue? please help, it's driving me quickly and certainly towards insanity.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

same thing to me here, what i am doing to fix that is to delete that file or folder from the file system and after that delete it from visual studio.

Comment: yep this is what I do too. ridiculous isn't it?

Comment: faced the similar issue in VS 2019. this process worked for me as well.

Answer (score 2):

This is happened to me because previously I opened file in browser to see what is the content. Probably IIS locked files under this folder so it does not let you delete them.

Do iisreset and try again, it will release lock and you can delete it from visual studio.

Comment: I was running "ng server" which apparently locked a folder.

Answer (score 1):

You are probably trying to delete a file in a folder for which you don't have permission. Try to move your files to another folder or run Visual Studio as administrator.

Answer (score 0):

This may happen if you do not have folder permissions within windows itself. Give the user folder permissions (full control) for the folder containing the solution and make sure those permissions are inherited by children of the folder. Once that is done (in the case of one of our employees) folders can be deleted from within visual studio.